# Transfering data from Parent to Child and back in VUE

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

**Main features:**

AddNewModal.vue (This is a modal with a form component) (Parent)
Form Component is dynamic and loaded with: Form.vue. (Child)

**What is happening?**

- The modal opens up
- I want to keep the Form data in one place, I have now named it within the data function at AddNewModal.vue. (Is this the right thing to do?)
- The form is built by Forms.vue
- I need the ref and value that I Emit to AddNewModal.vue (parent)
- Within AddNewModal.vue I eventually want to send the data to an API endpoint with a function when you click on: "Continue".

This is all going well. However, I wonder if this could not be done better/easier/better. Most important for me to be answered is:

1. Is this a good approach, or do I need to change? What?
2. `this.form[Object.keys(data)] = Object.values(data)[0]` - I don't like this. Is there a better way to get the data from the Child and work like this way? Let me know!

**File: AddNewModal.vue (Parent)**

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    :id="'modalAddItem' + processingData.structure.name"
    centered
    size="lg"
    title="Add new"
    @show="showSubmitButton"
  >
    <form class="form" v-on:submit.prevent="addNewItem('modalAddItem')">
      <Form
          v-if="processingData" :processing-data="processingData.structure" @refresh="returnData"
      />
    </form>

    <template #modal-footer="{ cancel, hide }">
      <b-button class="mr-auto" size="sm" @click="cancel()">Cancel</b-button>
      <span :class="spinner"></span>
      <b-button
        v-if="submitButton"
        size="sm"
        variant="primary"
        @click="addNewItem('modalAddItem')"
        >Continue</b-button
      >
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Form from '@/components/forms/Form'

export default {
  props: ['processingData'],
  components: {
    Form
  },
  data() {
    return {
      submitButton: true,
      spinner: '',
      form: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    returnData(data) {
      this.form[Object.keys(data)] = Object.values(data)[0]
    },
    addNewItem(modalId){
      axios.....
    }
 }
}
```

**File: Form.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group row" v-for="field in JSON.parse(processingData.fields)" :key="field.label">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div v-if="field.type == 'text'" :class="'col-' + field.cols">
                    <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
                    <input
                        class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
                        type="text"
                        :ref="field.field"
                        @input="getS(field.field, $event.target.value)"
                    />
                </div>

                <div v-else-if="field.type == 'date'" :class="'col-' + field.cols">
                    <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" type="datetime-local" value="2011-08-19T13:45:00" id="example-datetime-local-input">
                </div>

                <div v-else-if="field.type == 'select2'" :class="'col-' + field.cols">
                    <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
                    <select class="form-select" data-control="select2" data-placeholder="Select an option">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'Form',
    props: {
        processingData: Object
    },
    components: {
        //Input
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
        'settingsCountries', 'getStatuses', 'getTags'
        ]),
    },
    methods: {
        getS(e, value) {
    
            var object = {};
            object[e] = value;

            this.$emit('refresh', object);
        },
    }
}
```

I like to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) - put your form inside your modal and provide a default slot inside the form. Then any other component can use the slot to render whatever it needs, and the data will be kept inside the responsible component.

```html
<template>
  <my-modal :value="value">
    <my-form @submit.prevent="$emit('submit')">
      <slot />
    </my-form>
  </my-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  props:
  {
    value:
    {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I do load the component Form, to load my form. Can you provide me an example of code?